# How to access location change in background for Google Maps android API v2?

Tags: android, location, android-maps-v2

In my app I am using [Google Maps android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) and I have to get the current location coordinates on the change in location even when my app is in the background and do certain task. How can I do this?

**EDIT :**

Here is my code for tracking location

**LocationService.java**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

String TAG = "LocationService";

LocationManager mylocManager;
LocationTracker mylocListener;  

String myprovider;
database obj = new database(this);

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{    
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mylocManager!=null)
    {
        mylocManager.removeUpdates(mylocListener);
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

    mylocManager   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mylocListener  = new LocationTracker();

    Location loc = null;

    for(String myprovider:mylocManager.getAllProviders())
    {
       loc = mylocManager.getLastKnownLocation(myprovider);
       if(loc!=null)
       {
           Log.d(TAG,"Updating with last known location");
           updateLocation(loc);
           break;
       }   
    }

    if(Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic"))
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"App running on emulator");
        mylocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mylocListener);            
    }
    else if(mylocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"GPS Provider available");
        mylocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mylocListener);
    }
    else if(mylocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
         Log.d(TAG,"NETWORK Provider available");
        mylocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mylocListener);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.w(TAG,"No provider found. Stopping service");
        stopSelf();

    }  
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}




public class LocationTracker  implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Updating exact coordinates");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateLocation(loc);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) 
    {
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create a `Service` that will run even when you application is in the background.
This `Service` will have to implement or have a `LocationListener` object.

When `onLocationChanged` is triggered you could perform your task, as this indicates that you have received a new location update.

Comment: I wrote the code for that. But it is not accessing my GPS at all.

Comment: would you mind to open a new question with your code, and post here a link to it?

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please look into the upated one?

Comment: the code looks ok, where are you trying to run this? what method of requestLocationUpdates is run? meaning what is the log output?

Comment: I added the service in my manifest. `<service
            android:name="LocationService"
            android:label="MyLocationService" >
        </service>`

Comment: +1 for reminding me about running the service! I am using this code in my MainActivity. `Intent locationService = new Intent( this, LocationService.class );
  startService( locationService );`

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the issue for getting the location update in background. Could you please share the code.? It helps me a lot.